# apache rewrite rules for controller directory

Tags: php, apache, model-view-controller, mod-rewrite, controller

I have controller directory where is controller files located.

I want to do this

> sitename.com/test.php
>
> not
>
> sitename.com/controller/test.php

how to rewrite rules with apache?

Comment: So what you want is to go from a request to sitename.com/controller/test.php to sitename.com/test.php?

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to look into [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) in your [.htaccess](http://www.desiquintans.com/cleanurls)

Adding a rewrite rule in your .htaccess is simple. First, activate mod_rewrite by adding this line to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

Then add your rule to redirect your pages:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /controller/$1
```